# Jquery colorbox not working after gridview page change

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, colorbox

I am having issue with Jquery colorbox with gridview paging.
When First time page is loaded colorbox is working fine but when I change gridview page through paging its not working.

Here is my javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $(".example6").colorbox({
                iframe: true, innerWidth: 425, innerHeight: 173, onClosed: function () {

                    ($get('<%= btnInsertData_dummy.ClientID %>')).click();
                }
            });

            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);


        });

        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {

            $(".example6").colorbox({
                iframe: true, innerWidth: 425, innerHeight: 173, onClosed: function () {

                    var path = sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.pathname;
                    var myArray = new Array();
                    myArray = path.split('/');
                    if (myArray[1].toString() != "Default.aspx") {
                        ($get('<%= btnInsertData_dummy.ClientID %>')).click();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

and in gridview I am binding hyperlink on Rowdatabound

```
if (e.RowType != GridViewRowType.Data) return;

var securrityKey = e.GetValue("str_securitykey");
System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink grdHyper =
grid.FindRowCellTemplateControl(e.VisibleIndex, null, "grdhyper")
as System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink;
if (securrityKey.ToString() != "")
{
    grdHyper.Visible = false;
}
else
{
    var number = e.GetValue("lng_rndnum");
    var lngId = e.GetValue("lng_id");
    grdHyper.CssClass = "example6 cboxElement";
    grdHyper.NavigateUrl = "GenerateSecurityKey.aspx?number=" + number.ToString() + "&id=" + lngId.ToString();
}
```

and its not working after paging is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from `add_endRequest` to `add_pageLoaded` in your jquery code. And remove your `(document).ready(function(){` jquery code and placed your code of colorbox method inside `add_pageLoaded` method. Hope this might solve your issue.